# C-Server Socket become wrong Packet

Tags: java, c, sockets, utf-8

I have the following problem:

- I have a Java-client using the apache mina framework to send string.
- I wrote a C server to receive the string.
- So, I tried to send an utf8 character to the server:myStringToSend = "Ä"
- I debugged the mina source to see the packet in byte or hex and the mina convert the string well, so it sent `0xC3` `0x84`.
- I also check the sent packet in wireshark network viewer and It see also `0xC3` `0x84` as packet, all ok.
- But my C-server receive the following bytes: `FFFFFFC3FFFFFF84`

I don't know what's going wrong?

The code of my C-Server:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define TOOBIG 100000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
WSADATA wsa;
int i, c, iResult, iSendResult, outputCounter;

SOCKET listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET, clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct sockaddr_in server, client; 
char *message;

char sendbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
unsigned char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != NO_ERROR)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
printf("Initialised.\n");     

if((listenSocket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , IPPROTO_TCP )) == INVALID_SOCKET) //IPv4, TCP
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

printf("Socket created.\n");

memset(&server, '0', sizeof(server));
memset(sendbuf, '0', sizeof(sendbuf)); 

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
//server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7F000001); //localhost - 127.0.0.1
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
//server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.48.53.166");
server.sin_port = htons(7368); 

if( bind(listenSocket ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(listenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

puts("Bind done");

listen(listenSocket, 10); 

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");


c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

message = "{\"id\":2,\"result\":{\"code\":\"999\",\"message\":\"AddPageRange StartIndex don't match Inspection Counter\"},\"Client_ID\":\"PQCS1\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"Protocol\":\"2H\"}";

while( (clientSocket = accept(listenSocket , (struct sockaddr *)NULL, NULL)) != INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    puts("Connection accepted");        
    do {
        iResult = recv(clientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            recvbuf[iResult] = '\0';
            outputCounter = 0;
            while(recvbuf[outputCounter] != '\0')
                printf("%X", (unsigned char)recvbuf[outputCounter++]);              
            iSendResult = send( clientSocket, message, strlen(message), 0 );
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(clientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
            printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    } while( iResult > 0 );

 }
if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("accept failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
closesocket(listenSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use `unsigned char` instead of `char` for both `sendbuf[]` and `recvbuf[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recvbuf is of type char which is suspect is signed on your platform. Both bytes of your message are > 127(decimal) and so are seen as being negative.  The printf("%X") format specifier expects an integer (32 bit on your platform by the look of it) so the number gets sign extended (fill the most significant 24 bits of the integer with the most significant bit of the byte).

Try printing out how many bytes you received.  Also change your printf to

```
printf("%X",  ((int)recvbuf[outputCounter++]) & 0xff);
```

Comment: A bit complex to just convert a signed value to an unsigned one. A simpler solution could be `printf("%X",  (unsigned char)recvbuf[outputCounter++]);` or to declare `unsigned char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];`.

Comment: I tried to change the type of recvbuf to unsigned char but the thing is the method recv() don't accept unsigned char for this parameter. I get a compile error: "cannot convert parameter 2 from unsigned char[512] to char* "

Comment: @user2963830 The second parameter of [recv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) is an `void *`. It accept all pointers. So probably you wrote something bad. Add the modified code to the post.

Comment: so i added the modifed code above. I use visual studio and the editor tell that the methos signature is: int_stdcall recv(SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags)

Comment: ...good that sometime someone remember me why I got rid of msvc

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with `printf`.

Looking at [The Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

> **o, u, x, X**
>
> **The unsigned int argument** is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) notation. The letters abcdef are used for x conversions; the letters ABCDEF are used for X conversions. The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with zeros. The default precision is 1. When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So, using `%X` as format specifier, your data is promoted do `unsigned int` and you have to pass it selecting only the byte you want to be printed:

```
printf("Byte %d: %X\n", outputCounter, recvbuf[outputCounter++] & 0xFF);
```